# Can Minecraft be played in an isometric view

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been thinking of trying Minecraft.  I would like to know if Minecraft allows you to play with an isometric,  top down view instead of the cumbersome first person view?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible without mods.

Comment: It's surely doable with mods. But the gameplay isn't suited for this. If it's the perspective what bothers you in minecraft, try another game as it seems you're looking for another game experience than minecraft offers.

Comment: I don't know why so many people are voting it down.  Once it is on zero further voting down is usually required only for questions which are obviously obnoxious in both content and from.

Answer (score 4):

You can play in a third-person view, if that is what you're asking. Pressing F5 toggles through different view modes. However i would recommend first person view, things like exploring cave ceilings for ores, and small enclosed spaces in general are easier with first person.

Comment: I was asking about isometric view like for eg: simcity,  or even the sims,  rather than a 3rd person view. I agree for small confined spaces first person would be fine,  but for large expansive outdoor environment,  isometric view would be easier to interact with

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments and other answers, this is really not possible without mods. However third-person view does provide a wider perspective, though clearly this is not on the scale you are looking for.

The multi-level and vast terrain that this game offers is far too complex for an isometric view to be considered "usable" in Minecraft. Even in third person, it can be sometimes tricky to get the same view that first person provides.

The difference between games like Sims/Sim City and Minecraft is the in the Sims game you are very much third party, making other people do things, whereas in Minecraft, it very much is a first-person interactive game. *You* are the one digging, and exploring and farming, not a Sim. It's a more personal experience in that sense.